# How to track which tables the database wrote data to?

Tags: sql, database, odbc, sybase, sqlanywhere

I use "Lexware Warenwirtschaft Premium 2014" (a well-known merchandise management software in Germany). It uses Sybase as a database. I connect to the database by using a ODBC connection(SQL Anywhere driver). The database has 800+ tables. For example when Lexware creates a new Article, it writes data into different tables.

Is there a way to track into which tables Lexware wrote data?

Answer (score 0):

As an ad-hoc measure you could switch on ODBC tracing, and then review the contents.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274551 tells you how to do this from a Windows client, and you can find similar information for Linux/Unix and other clients.

You'd then have to parse the trace file to see which queries were inserted into. The first step would probably be to isolate all the SQLPrepare and SQLExecDirect statements, and check them for INSERT, UPDATE and other relevant Sybase statements.

Note that this is not something you'd want as an ongoing solution, just a way to find out what an ODBC client does if you do not have access to e.g. logging information on the database itself. However, the trace slows down execution and would generate a very large trace file if you left it running for any significant period.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. Whatever this program does behind the interface is hidden in its binaries and unreadable for humans, so you can't read the code to see which tables are altered.

You might be able to figure out which table was edited last, depending on the SQL-Server and it's version.

Comment: It's SQLAnywhere - Not SQLServer